# Active link while editing in jquery rich text editor

Tags: jquery, rich-text-editor

Is there any way to navigate via a link created inside the active jquery rich text editor? Similar to CTRL+Click in MsWord while editing. The link is created, but by default is not selectable within the editor.

Comment: You can use browser's feature! for example, perform a secondary click on link in Chrome and select "open link in new tab". that will work for you